# Rails - how to group/map records from database into a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, select, group-by

I fetch data from database and they have this structure:

```
@articles = Article.where(...)
```

in `@data`:

```
id | author_id | article_name | ...
1  | 1         | Morning      | ...
2  | 1         | Wednesday    | ...
3  | 2         | Hallo!       | ...
```

When I need to find out how many articles does have an author, I do it this way:

```
<% articles = Hash[@articles.group_by(&:author_id).map {|k,v| [k,v.length]}] %>
<% @data.uniq_by {|x| x["author_id"]}.each do |result| %>
  <%= articles[result.author_id] %>
```

But I would need to also fetch similarly also article names and access to them the same way as to the count of articles.
I would need something like this:

```
<%= articles2[result.author_id] %> # and this would print out "Morning,Wednesday" for the author with ID 1
```

Which method should I use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, not tested though

```
<% @articles.group_by(&:author_id).each do |id, articles| %>
  <%= articles.map(&:article_name).join(",") %> for author with ID: <%= id %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make the whole process a lot easier by using rails relations:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end
```

Then you can iterate over all the authors and grab the information you want:

```
<% @authors.each do |author| %>

  # number of articles
  <%= author.articles.count %>

  # list of article names
  <%= author.articles.pluck(:name).join(', ') %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'd need to modify the whole table structure, so that's why I need to do it this way.

Comment: @user984621 why would you have to change the table structure? the articles table already has an author_id column, it should be good to go

Comment: This will give an `N + 1` issue.